# What type of data return /dev/random by default?

Tags: linux, random, types

What type of data return /dev/random by default without any formatting with **od** (for example)?

I mean, what is the data type of these random symbols which we see when run **cat /dev/random** ?

Comment: It's a random number actually. I don't know whether it's 32 or 64 bits though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to cat it, it will result in jibberish.  You need to read it as a binary data.  od, for example will work.  Otherwise, you can read it in with c's `read` function, for example.

It is stored as a random stream of binary digits.

Comment: Why **cat** display it this way?

Comment: Because it is simply raw data.  Try `cat`ing an executable file.  It too will be jibberish.  The only files that you can view properly with `cat` are text files which contain ascii data, or properly formatted control characters.